# ASP.NET MVC : increase date limit 10 years in the view (.aspx)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net, date

I have an html datepicker to select the date. But when I want to select the year, I can only select 10 previous years or 10 future years.

For example, if we are in 2023, I can only see from 2013 to 2033:

[image]

But I want to select 2010 and I can't. I know that if I select 2013, then I can see another previous 10 years (now from 2003-2023):

[image]

But my question is I f I can increase that limit instead of 10 years, to 20 years. Is that possible? Something like this:

[image]

This is the code in the view:

```
<div class="filter"> <label for="MyDate">Date </label> <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "inputCenterDate", @style = "width:70px;" })%> </div> 

.inputCenterDate {
    text-align: center; 
    width: 80px;    
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 1.2em;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#Date").datepicker()
    .focusout(function (event) {//Format dd/MM/yy to dd/MM/yyyy
        var auxF = CheckDateCorrectFormat(this.value);
        if (auxF != "") this.value = auxF;
    });
```

Comment: It's all about the javascript.

Comment: I assume there are a jQuery that handle this date picker. Find it and configure it

Comment: This is what I have in the same view, in the "srcipt" part of the aspx: <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#Date").datepicker()
        .focusout(function (event) {//Format dd/MM/yy to dd/MM/yyyy
            var auxF = CheckDateCorrectFormat(this.value);
            if (auxF != "") this.value = auxF;
        });

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) and going from there.

Comment: This question is a JavaScript/jQuery question. Please remove the ASP.NET related tags.

Comment: Yeah!! The yearRange work!! Thank you  Heretic Monkey and NineBerry.